# Wait for all elements matching selector to be hidden

Tags: puppeteer

I have a page that contains multiple panels. While each panel is loading, it has a div with a `class=progress`. Once that panel is loaded, that same div gets the attribute of `display:none;`. I've tried `await page.waitForFunction() and waitForSelector()`, but they appear to evaluate to true when the first div becomes invisible. I want to wait until they are all invisible before I screenshot.

Comment: This question would benefit from a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe this

```
  let panels = await page.$$('.panels')
  let hiddenPanels = await page.$$('.panels' , {visible : false })
  while(panels.length != hiddenPanels.length )
  {
     await page.waitForTimeout(3000);
     hiddenPanels = await page.$$('.panels' , {visible : false }) ; 
  }
```

or just check the visible ones

```
  let visiblePanels = await page.$$('.panels' , {visible : true  })
  while(visiblePanels.length > 0  )
  {
     await page.waitForTimeout(3000);
     visiblePanels = await page.$$('.panels' , {visible : true }) ; 
  }
```

Comment: I used your logic, but for some reason the selector didn't work so I modified that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Please select this as the right answer if you find this solution was helpful and correct.

Do you means panels are iframes?

```
let allDivsHidden = false
do {
    let statesArray = []
    await page.waitForTimeout(100) // Or any number of time you like
    for (let i = 0; i < page.frames().length; i++) {
        statesArray.push( await page.frames()[i].evaluate(() => {
            return document.querySelector('.progress').style.display === 'none'
        }))
    }
    allDivsHidden = statesArray.filter(boolean => boolean === false).length === 0
} while (!allDivsHidden)
```

Comment: This looks great. I’ll give it a try tomorrow! The panels are really highchart SVGs inside of divs, loaded via xhr, not iframes.

Comment: This didn't work exactly, but I think it was the query selector. Thx for your help as it pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: My pleasure, you're welcome

Answer (score 0):

OK, thx to the answers from Max and Edi, I got it working. I'm also on an older version of node so created a "delay" function.

```
 let visiblePanels = await page.$$('div.progress-animation:not([style*="display: none;"])');
  //logger.info(visiblePanels.length);
  while(visiblePanels.length > 0  )
  {
    //logger.info("Waiting in loop...");
    await delay(500);
    visiblePanels = await page.$$("div.progress-animation:not([style*='display: none;'])");
  }
```

Thank you!

Comment: you're welcome , also you can use `await page.waitFor(500)` to delay the process in the older versions

Answer (score 0):

Use `waitForXPath`. Here an is my example

```
const element_1 = await page.waitForXPath('//div[not(@hidden)]');
expect(element_1).toBeDefined();
```